# Addition formulas for q-analogs of trigonometric functions

Tags: gamma-function, q-analogs, q-series, trigonometric-functions

Sine and Cosine functions possess notable formulas for addition of angles
$$
\sin(a+b) = \sin(a)\cos(b) + \cos(a)\sin(b) \qquad \text{or} \qquad \cos(a+b) = \cos(a)\cos(b) - \sin(a)\sin(b).
$$
One can come up with several $q$ analogs of trigonometric functions. For instance, from the relation
$$
\sin(\pi z) = \frac{\pi}{\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)},
$$
one can define the $q$-sine function as
$$
\sin_q(\pi z) = \frac{\pi}{\Gamma_q(z)\Gamma_q(1-z)}.
$$

My question is: Are there notable $q$ deformations of trigonometric functions satisfying addition formulas for angles?

Comment: There's [Gosper's q-trigonometric functions](https://oeis.org/A274621/a274621.pdf) but I believe that the addition formulae (and, indeed, most of the identities in the paper) are conjectural, and while it's easy to find a paper which proves the double-angle formulae I haven't seen one which proves the addition formulae.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks a lot. Formula (Add) at page 9 looks precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: Ernst, T. [A method for q-calculus](https://www.atlantis-press.com/article/622.pdf), J. Nonlinear Math. Phys. 10.4 (2003) pp 487-525 is also of interest, but I must be misunderstanding the notation because I can't see the relevance of Hahn addition in (3.22) and (3.23) or Ward-AlSalam addition in (4.35) to (4.42).

Comment: @PeterTaylor thanks again for the additional reference. I found that some of the identities by Gosper were proven by El Bachraoui and some co-authors; see for instance [link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X17310946?via%3Dihub).